# Make sure X server isn't already running?

Tags: xorg, gdm

Suddenly out of the blue I was able to start the X server but with many warnings on CentOS and then I tried to make sure it was shut down by going into /usr/bin and `gdm stop` but there is an error log which states:

```
[2148293.861] _XSERVTransSocketINETCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
[2148293.861] _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
[2148293.861]
Fatal server error:
[2148293.862] Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running
[2148293.862] (EE)
Please consult the CentOS support
         at http://wiki.centos.org/Documentation
 for help.
[2148293.862] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[2148293.862] (EE)
[2148293.862] Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

With `gdm stop` I get:

```
** (gdm-binary:25390): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or director
```

Comment: What's the connection between your title and your problem? What's the error log from? The description of what you've done is missing too many pieces.

Comment: This is my 3rd question regarding X server, I had given up on it when it mysteriously started and simultaneously I was trying to stop it but also figure out what the error log meant for why it would say make sure it is not already running when it was riddled with warnings and errors and I thought I had killed it.

Comment: I wanted to adamantly stop it and then try again and see what error I got.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the stated question, you can make sure whether the Xserver is running by issuing command:

```
ps -C Xorg
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for at the very least.