# Is X server running? xdpyinfo: unable to open display "" on Ubuntu 18.04 server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, x11, x-server, xvfb

I'm attempting to start a program that requires rendering a window (Unity Game) on a remote server that doesn't have a display attached to it. I wouldn't want to use `ssh -X` to forward rendering commands to my local machine. I'm trying to run the program in headless mode but still making use of the remote server's GPU, or use `Xvfb`, but I cannot
get it to work.

In the first step of this process, I try to **determine whether X server is already running**.
Upon sshing into the remote server, I ran

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

and it returns empty string. I thought that this means the X server is not running ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637005/how-to-check-if-x-server-is-running))

However, I encounter contradicting information:

- When running `ps ax | grep X`, I get

  ```
  2149 tty1     Sl+    0:03 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt1 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/121/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
  ```

  This means indeed X server is running (because of the Xorg executable). Running `ps -C Xorg` also shows PID 2149 ([reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122067/make-sure-x-server-isnt-already-running)).
- Also, when I run `Xvfb :0.0`, I get

  ```
  $ Xvfb :0.0
  _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: 
  ...SocketCreateListener() failed
  _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already 
  running
  (EE) 
  Fatal server error:
  (EE) Cannot establis
  ```

  This again seems to indicate that an X server is already running on `:0.0`.

However (again), when I run `xdpyinfo`, the utility for displaying information about an X server, I get

```
$ xdpyinfo
xdpyinfo:  unable to open display "".
```

and

```
$ xdpyinfo -display :0.0
No protocol specified
xdpyinfo:  unable to open display ":0.0".
```

This seems to tell me again that the X server is not running.

What is going on? Is the X server running?

As you may be able to tell I'm a newbie to X-server related issues. Please feel free point out any problem with my steps above, and suggest ways to resolve this. Thanks! There's a lot to learn.

Comment: [Here](/a/17278) the author proposes a way to find the locally-running servers: `(cd /tmp/.X11-unix && for x in X*; do echo ":${x#X}"; done)`. Can you try it? (It would be just enough to call `ls /tmp/.X11-unix`.)

Comment: There is a file `X0` in `/tmp/.X11-unix`

Comment: I managed to have a workaround on another server which definitely did not have X server running at first. I had to install Xorg and Xvfb, and I ran `sudo Xorg :0.0` and my application was able connect to that server. Interestingly `echo $DISPLAY` is still an empty string, yet `xdpyinfo :0.0` actually returns information.

Comment: `echo $DISPLAY` just outputs a value of the variable, whatever it is. If nobody has set it before, then it has no value (if anybody set it to a wrong value, then it has the wrong value). You might need **setting** `$DISPLAY` to a specific value (if you know a specific X server exists and want the subprocesses to use it by default), but **getting** the `$DISPLAY` doesn't really give any information except _“somebody has set a specific value”_ or _“nobody has set any value yet”_.

Comment: @sasha It seems like people have debated about whether `$DISPLAY` can be used to check X server is running: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637005/how-to-check-if-x-server-is-running . I feel that `xdpyinfo` is probably the right way to check

Comment: There seems to be a confusion between 2 concepts. `$DISPLAY` is a correct way for a _program_ to determine what X server _it should use_ (because there may be many X servers available; and the program shouldn't do anything unexpected for a user, behave in a non-standard way). But it's not a way for a _human being_ to detect which X servers _are actually available_ (because it's just an environment variable, nothing more; it's value may give a hint but can't be used as a proof).